How do I customize my Material Tailwind UI Carousel?
I've been working on my carousel using Material Tailwind and it works great!  The only issue that I am having is that some of the projects in my carousel have a white background in contrast to the white arrows that the carousel defaults too.  I want to continue using the material carousel, but I cannot figure out how to change the white arrows and navigation at the bottom.  Does anyone have any experience with customizing the Material Tailwind theme? When I look at the docs they seem to have a way to customize themes but it is not making sense to me currently.
Here is the code for my Carousel so far
export default function Projects() {
  return (
    <div id="projects" className="projects-div">
      <h2 className="text-4xl relative top-10 text-center mb-20">Projects</h2>
      <div className="container">
        <Carousel transition={{ duration: 1 }} className="carousel rounded-xl">
          <a href="https://nixfixllc.com/">
            <img src="nfl.png" className="carousel-img w-full object-cover" />
          </a>

          <a href="https://mysticmeditation.netlify.app">
            <img src="mysticmeditation.png" className="carousel-img  w-full" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://cheery-pastelito-184353.netlify.app/">
            <img src="rockpapertank.png" className="carousel-img  w-full" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://rad-frangipane-ab7eaa.netlify.app/">
            <img src="pupbowl.png" className="carousel-img  w-full" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://astonishing-dolphin-abeb89.netlify.app/">
            <img src="qwirty.png" className="carousel-img  w-full" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://ornate-panda-539b81.netlify.app/">
            <img src="secondsite.png" className="carousel-img  w-full" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://vocal-zuccutto-ced39d.netlify.app/">
            <img src="strangersThings.png" className="carousel-img  w-full" />
          </a>
          <a href="https://papaya-praline-b8ce49.netlify.app/">
            <img src="tictactoe.png" className="carousel-img  w-full " />
          </a>
          <a href="https://amca.onrender.com/">
            <img src="amca.png" className="carousel-img  w-full " />
          </a>
          <a href="https://fabulous-klepon-630ec6.netlify.app/">
            <img src="firstsite.png" className="carousel-img  w-full " />
          </a>
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

I have tried to add the IconButton inside of the Carousel using the prevArrow and nextArrow props, but it has done nothing but remove the arrow entirely.

Which Carousel component are you using? Mui doesn't have Carousel component.
Are you using react-material-ui-carousel?
It would be helpful if you can create a sandbox.

https://www.material-tailwind.com/docs/react/carousel

Check if this helps
